# Using SQLite in PHPUnit causes disk I/O error

Tags: php, sqlite, io, phpunit

I am using `SQLite` as test database for my `PHPUnit` tests.

My tests typically involves multiple read/writes to the db. Each test has a PHPUnit `setUp()` and `tearDown()` method which creates and deletes the db when each test method runs.

While it works fine, sometimes I would get this error:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error`

There's also a `.db-journal` file left hanging around when this error happens.

Any ideas how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: partition size, disk quota?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone you mean if my db is exceeding diskspace? not at all, the db is tiny, just a few kb.

Comment: This error is frequently shown when the user account writing to the db runs out of space. When working as root from shell you do not realize any quota, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I am certain I have ample diskspace left

Comment: is the file on an nfs or alike?

Comment: @Jakumi Nope its on Windows NTFS. But it's containerized like this: Windows 7 (host) > CentOS (Vagrant)  > Debian (Docker), if that matters.

Comment: I looked up your error message and it led me to a page where it essentially said, that in nfs a lock on the file produced this error (which might not always be the cause). if your tests rapidly create and delete files, maybe that's the reason here too. My personal approach with temporary files is, to either use `tempnam`/`tmpfile` or give it a unique name (`uniqid`), to avoid collision. this of course under the assumption, that this is the cause. since it's not a big change at all, you could try and report back your results (or, if it works, write an answer and fetch some rep ^^)

Comment: @Jakumi Unfortunately the issue still persists after giving it a `uniqid()`

Comment: how many tests are you running?

Comment: @Jakumi Just about 20 tests but the queries in those tests are about 100.

Comment: that doesn't sound that much, tbh. to rule out virtualized bs, have a non-virtualized debian laying around to check? ^^ otherwise, I'm out of (cheap) ideas and don't know enough about the details, tbh.